# How to get the source code for the javax:javaee-api-6.0.jar

Tags: maven, java-ee-6

I use the javax:javaee-api-6.0.jar maven artifact.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I would like to download its source code with the dependency:sources mvn goal.
I was looking for the sources in the official maven repositories, but I still can't find it.

Could you give me a bit of advice on how can I achieve my object?
Thank you.

Comment: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11389

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mich is correct.

The purpose of the *javaee-api* module is to satisfy compile-time dependencies (That is why the Maven scope is set to **provided**). The module contains interface declarations (or contract) which must be satisfied by the J2EE container you plan to use.

If you really need/want to see the source code, I'd suggest taking a look at one of the open source J2EE containers.

Comment: Your link is stale / dead.

Comment: @kevinarpe Thanks.... Just removed it... The joys of forensic computing :-)

Answer (score 1):

see if these are any good and if they work for you http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/openejb/javaee-api/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (it has sources attached)

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
     <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
```

It pulls in a huge number of dependencies, but as they are all provided you do effectively not alter your artifact.