# Maven cannot download sources for javax:javaee-web-api

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3

I use IntelliJ Idea. Inside IntelliJ Idea, I want to debug some code inside the class `javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.getViewMap` which is provided by the library `javaee-web-api`.

I command IntelliJ to download sources but IntelliJ says:

```
6:21:41 PM Cannot download sources
           Sources not found for:
           javax:javaee-web-api:6.0
```

I wonder why Maven cannot find the sources for `javaee-web-api`?

This is the dependency statement in my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457810/how-to-get-the-source-code-for-the-javaxjavaee-api-6-0-jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no source jar uploaded to maven central for this version of the artifact, see [Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-web-api/6.0/). Version `7.0` has got [source code jars](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-web-api/7.0/), if that helps.

**References:**

- [Maven - Java EE 6 Web Profile Javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205768/maven-java-ee-6-web-profile-javadocs)